# Typewriter in TikZ node

Tags: tikz-pgf, typewriter

A small example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz{\node[text width=1cm]{\tt totot\\t t t};}
\tikz{\node{\parbox{1cm}{\tt totot\\t t t}};}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

As you can see, alignment is not respected in the first TikZ node but is right in the `\parbox`. Is it a bug of TikZ? Why the difference?

Comment: You can also use the following example, `\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text width=1cm,font=\ttfamily]{t t t};
\node[font=\ttfamily] at (0,0.5) {t t t};
\end{tikzpicture}
` when you tell TikZ to respect line breaks via `align` or `text width` internally it switches from an `\hbox` to a `minipage` environment.

Comment: but if i use a minipage instead of a parbox, it is still correctly aligned.

Comment: What did you use for width of the minipage?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For some reason I can't really well understand, in a `\node` the parameters `\spaceskip` and `\xspaceskip` are set to non zero values; when `\spaceskip` is non zero, TeX uses it for the interword space instead of the default stored in the current font information.

Try the following example

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz{\node[text width=3cm]{\ttfamily
totot\\
t t t\\
\the\spaceskip\ \the\xspaceskip\\
\spaceskip=0pt totot\\t t t};}
\end{document}
```

and see that setting `\spaceskip=0pt` cures the problem.

[image]

The option to set is `text badly ragged` (apparently TikZ doesn't like normal ragged right and adds to the LaTeX definition also the Plain TeX one when calling `text ragged` which is the default).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text width=1cm,font=\ttfamily,text badly ragged]{totot\\t t t};
\node[font=\ttfamily] at (1.5,0){\parbox{1cm}{totot\\t t t}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If an option for deciding about the `\spaceskip` doesn't exist in TikZ, it should.

Comment: Can it be the side effect of `\nullfont`?

Comment: @percusse I don't think so; the `\spaceskip` must be explicitly set, in order it changes value. Maybe you can suggest a TikZ style option to set it to zero, rather than using that awful trick of mine.

Comment: the key `text justified` sets `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` to `0pt` and produces the desired effect. In general, the internal macro `\tikz@text@action` is executed just before the node contents and is where all the skip stuff is sorted out, so a new style could `\def` this macro.

Comment: @MarkWibrow The problem is in the fact that TikZ uses Plain TeX's `\raggedright` rather than LaTeX's.

Answer (score 5):

In a `parbox` the text is justified and in a `node` with `textwidth` specified, the text is `raggedright` aligned. You can justify the text inside `node`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\tikz{\node[text width=1cm]{\justifying\tt totot\\t t t};}
\tikz{\node{\parbox{1cm}{\tt totot\\t t t}};}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Hence it is not a bug IMO.

Not related, but you can consider using `\ttfamily` instead of two letter `\tt`.

Comment: If I use raggedright in the parbox, it is still correctly aligned.

Comment: @Xoff: That, I don't know :-(

Comment: It works on this example, but not on more complex ones. The only way to get it right is to have fixed width spaces.

Comment: @xoff can you show one such example?

Comment: You're right, there is no such example, your answer is good but : I don't need \justifying, I just need to use package ragged2e. So I suspect this package redefine something that is used by tikz...