# Bad word spacing in TikZ using `text width` and `\fontsize`

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, fontsize

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[text width=20em]{This is};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[text width=20em]{\fontsize{30}{40}\selectfont This is};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[text width=20em]{\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont This is};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node{\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont This is};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node{\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont\spaceskip 0pt This is};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[text width=20em,text badly ragged]{\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont This is};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Produces

[image: Result of the above code]

So we see that when using `text width`, setting `\fontsize` doesn't change the spacing as it should, probably because of what [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) described in [Typewriter in TikZ node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132748/8547). The fixes he suggested there do work but are a bit cumbersome. Is there an easier way to get the right spacing? Should a bug be filed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TikZ has to deal with the size of the box (or minipage in this case where text size or alignment keys are used) differently for allocating enough space for the drawing purposes. So there are some preparation steps involved before the node contents are placed inside a node area that is handled by TeX typesetting. Hence, TikZ offers some flexibility to inject text font modifications via `font` key.

As egreg points out in the linked question, it doesn't solve everything and involves certain choices but usually it is sufficient for things like this. The problem here is that TikZ prepares itself for certain font state but then in the node contents the font information is altered thus some weirdness is produced. It begs for a better surgery but I am not so sure if I can do proper justice to the choices made.

Fortunately, font size commands are taken into account by the font key hence injected in the right place, thus the following works:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text width=20em,font=\fontsize{30}{40}\selectfont ]{This is};
\end{tikzpicture}
```