# tikz - annotation text block with matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I wish to annotate a hex text block with matrix. and the matrix output should be similar to listings output. so I add a listings above for compare.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\lstset{frame=tb,
    aboveskip=3mm,
    belowskip=3mm,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
    numbers=none,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
}
\begin{document}
    \small\ttfamily\begin{lstlisting}
00000000: ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01  ......JFIF......
00000010: 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 03 02 02 03 02 02 03  .......C........
00000020: 03 03 03 04 03 03 04 05 08 05 05 04 04 05 0a 07  ................
00000030: 07 06 08 0c 0a 0c 0c 0b 0a 0b 0b 0d 0e 12 10 0d  ................ 
    \end{lstlisting}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
 \matrix (m) [
matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,
row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
nodes={anchor=center,minimum width=1ex,text width=2ex,inner sep=0,outer sep=0},
] 
{
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&:& &f&f& &d&8& &f&f& &e&0& &0&0& &1&0& &4&a& &4&6& &4&9& &4&6& &0&0& &0&1& &0&1& &0&0& &0&0& &0&1& & &.&.&.&.&.&.&J&F&I&F&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&:& &0&0& &0&1& &0&0& &0&0& &f&f& &d&b& &0&0& &4&3& &0&0& &0&3& &0&2& &0&2& &0&3& &0&2& &0&2& &0&3& & &.&.&.&.&.&.&.&C&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&2&0&:& &0&3& &0&3& &0&3& &0&4& &0&3& &0&3& &0&4& &0&5& &0&8& &0&5& &0&5& &0&4& &0&4& &0&5& &0&a& &0&7& & &.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&3&0&:& &0&7& &0&6& &0&8& &0&c& &0&a& &0&c& &0&c& &0&b& &0&a& &0&b& &0&b& &0&d& &0&e& &1&2& &1&0& &0&d& & &.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
};  
   \draw[red,line width=1pt] (m-1-11.south west) rectangle (m-1-16.north east);
   \draw[red,<-] (m-1-16.north east) -- ++(1,0.2) -- ++(5,0) node[pos=1,right] {ISO};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I adjust the parameters to get similar result between matrix output and listings output? Or any other choice for such annotation purpose?
[image]

Comment: You can use `tikzmark` to annotate the listing.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Good suggestion, but I prefer to use table cell to access the elements.

Comment: If you are open to something that allows you to annotate the code without actually changing it, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446081/194703). This allows you to have the code in a separate file even, and still to access everything.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Great information, is it for matlab code only, when I try it with my text, the position sounds weird.would you please give a modify for my specific text. (annotate the ff 48 ff part.

Comment: You have already an accepted answer... so if you are happy with what you got, I am not going to add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\lstset{frame=tb,
    aboveskip=3mm,
    belowskip=3mm,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
    numbers=none,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
}
\begin{document}
    \small\ttfamily\begin{lstlisting}
00000000: ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01  ......JFIF......
00000010: 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 03 02 02 03 02 02 03  .......C........
00000020: 03 03 03 04 03 03 04 05 08 05 05 04 04 05 0a 07  ................
00000030: 07 06 08 0c 0a 0c 0c 0b 0a 0b 0b 0d 0e 12 10 0d  ................ 
    \end{lstlisting}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
 \matrix (m) [
matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,
row sep =15\pgflinewidth,
column sep = -7.5\pgflinewidth,
nodes={anchor=center,minimum width=1ex,text width=2ex,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt},
] 
{
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&:& &f&f& &d&8& &f&f& &e&0& &0&0& &1&0& &4&a& &4&6& &4&9& &4&6& &0&0& &0&1& &0&1& &0&0& &0&0& &0&1& & &.&.&.&.&.&.&J&F&I&F&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&:& &0&0& &0&1& &0&0& &0&0& &f&f& &d&b& &0&0& &4&3& &0&0& &0&3& &0&2& &0&2& &0&3& &0&2& &0&2& &0&3& & &.&.&.&.&.&.&.&C&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&2&0&:& &0&3& &0&3& &0&3& &0&4& &0&3& &0&3& &0&4& &0&5& &0&8& &0&5& &0&5& &0&4& &0&4& &0&5& &0&a& &0&7& & &.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&3&0&:& &0&7& &0&6& &0&8& &0&c& &0&a& &0&c& &0&c& &0&b& &0&a& &0&b& &0&b& &0&d& &0&e& &1&2& &1&0& &0&d& & &.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.\\
};  
   \node[fit= (m-1-11)(m-1-17),draw,red]{};
   \draw[red,<-] (m-1-16.north east) -- ++(1,0.2) -- ++(5,0) node[pos=1,right] {ISO};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks, but the red rectangle a little bit weird. it should cover the four char's but sounds like only half is covered.

Comment: Look at my updated answer.  Otherwise, specify exactly what you want about this red frame.

Comment: Great, fits done good job! it's exactly what I want. many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

refer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419759/how-to-annotate-listings-in-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1) SO, I modify it with hardcode hex numbers. it's a little bit long but now sure if any regrex support for listings keyword define! Maybe someone can help improve it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,shadows,decorations.pathreplacing}
\makeatletter
\newif\iflst@linemark
\lst@AddToHook{EveryLine}{%
    \begingroup
    \advance\c@lstnumber by 1\relax
    \pgfmark{line-\lst@name-\the\c@lstnumber-start}%
    \endgroup
}
\lst@AddToHook{EOL}{\pgfmark{line-\lst@name-\the\c@lstnumber-end}%
    \global\lst@linemarktrue
}
\lst@AddToHook{OutputBox}{%
    \iflst@linemark
    \pgfmark{line-\lst@name-\the\c@lstnumber-first}%
    \global\lst@linemarkfalse
    \fi
}
\def\tkzlst@fnum#1\relax#2\@STOP{%
    \def\@test{#2}%
    \ifx\@test\@empty
    \def\tkzlst@start{0}%
    \else
    \@tempcnta=#1\relax
    \advance\@tempcnta by -1\relax
    \def\tkzlst@start{\the\@tempcnta}%
    \fi
}
\lst@AddToHook{Init}{%
    \expandafter\tkzlst@fnum\lst@firstnumber\relax\@STOP
    \pgfmark{line-\lst@name-\tkzlst@start-start}%
}
\newcommand\balloon[4]{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\pgf@temp{%
        #3-1
    }%
    \iftikzmark{line-#2-\pgf@temp-start}{%
        \iftikzmark{line-#2-#3-first}{%
            %\xdef\b@lines{({pic cs:line-#2-\pgf@temp-start} -| {pic cs:line-#2-#3-first})}%
            \xdef\b@lines{($({pic cs:line-#2-\pgf@temp-start} -| {pic cs:line-#2-#3-first})!.5!({pic cs:line-#2-#3-first})$)}
        }{%
            \iftikzmark{line-#2-#3-start}{%
                %\xdef\b@lines{({pic cs:line-#2-\pgf@temp-start} -| {pic cs:line-#2-#3-start})}%
                \xdef\b@lines{($({pic cs:line-#2-\pgf@temp-start} -| {pic cs:line-#2-#3-first})!.5!({pic cs:line-#2-#3-first}) $)}
            }{%
                \xdef\b@lines{(pic cs:line-#2-\pgf@temp-start)}%
            }%
        }%
    }{%
        \xdef\b@lines{}%
    }%
    \foreach \k in {#3,...,#4} {%
        \iftikzmark{line-#2-\k-first}{%
            \xdef\b@lines{\b@lines (pic cs:line-#2-\k-first) }
        }{}
        \iftikzmark{line-#2-\k-end}{%
            \xdef\b@lines{\b@lines (pic cs:line-#2-\k-end) }
        }{}
    }%
    \ifx\b@lines\pgfutil@empty
    \else
    \edef\pgf@temp{\noexpand\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\noexpand\node[fit={\b@lines},balloon] (#1) {};}%
    \pgf@temp
    \fi
}
\makeatother
% Define styles for balloons, lines and marked code areas
\tikzset{
    balloon/.style={
        draw,
        fill=blue!20,
        opacity=0.4,
        inner sep=2pt,
        rounded corners=2pt
    },
}
\newcounter{tmlistings}
\newcommand\makenode[2]{%
    \tikz[baseline=0pt, remember picture] { \node[anchor=base,#1/.try,inner sep=0] (m-\the\value{tmlistings}) {#2}; }%
    \stepcounter{tmlistings}%
}
\lstdefinelanguage{HEX}{
    alsoletter=0123456789,
    keywords={
        00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,0a,0b,0c,0d,0e,0f,
        10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,1a,1b,1c,1d,1e,1f,
        20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,2a,2b,2c,2d,2e,2f,
        30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,3a,3b,3c,3d,3e,3f,
        40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,4a,4b,4c,4d,4e,4f,
        50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,5a,5b,5c,5d,5e,5f,
        60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,6a,6b,6c,6d,6e,6f,
        70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,7a,7b,7c,7d,7e,7f,
        80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,8a,8b,8c,8d,8e,8f,
        90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,9a,9b,9c,9d,9e,9f,
        a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,aa,ab,ac,ad,ae,af,
        b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,ba,bb,bc,bd,be,bf,
        c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,ca,cb,cc,cd,ce,cf,
        d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,da,db,dc,dd,de,df,
        e0,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9,ea,eb,ec,ed,ee,ef,
        f0,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,fa,fb,fc,fd,fe,ff
    },
    keywordstyle=\makenode{keyword},
    sensitive=false, %not case-sensitive
} %
% Command to draw a balloon over two anchors
\newcommand*{\ann}[4][]{%[red]{from}{to}{desc}
    \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.5em,raise=2pt},decorate,ultra thick,#1]
    (#2) -- node [align=center,anchor=west,right=5pt] {#4} (#3);
}%
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=HEX,name=list1,numbers=left,firstnumber=1]
00000000: ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01  ......JFIF......
00000010: 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 03 02 02 03 02 02 03  .......C........
00000020: 03 03 03 04 03 03 04 05 08 05 05 04 04 05 0a 07  ................
00000030: 07 06 08 0c 0a 0c 0c 0b 0a 0b 0b 0d 0e 12 10 0d  ................ 
00000000: ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01  ......JFIF......
00000010: 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 03 02 02 03 02 02 03  .......C........
00000020: 03 03 03 04 03 03 04 05 08 05 05 04 04 05 0a 07  ................
00000030: 07 06 08 0c 0a 0c 0c 0b 0a 0b 0b 0d 0e 12 10 0d  ................ 
    \end{lstlisting}
    \balloon{comment}{list1}{3}{3}
    \balloon{comment}{list1}{4}{4}
    \balloon{comment}{list1}{7}{7}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (pic cs:line-list1-5-first);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (pic cs:line-list1-5-start);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (pic cs:line-list1-5-end);
        \node[above] at (0,0) {Line 5};
        \node[fit=(m-0)(m-2),draw,red]{};
        \draw[red,<-] (m-2.north east) -- ++(1,0.2) -- ++(12,0) node[pos=1,right] {ISO};
        \node[fit=(m-32)(m-34),draw,red]{};
        \draw[red,<-] (m-34.north east) -- ++(1,0.2) -- ++(12,0) node[pos=1,right] {ISO};
        \ann[red]{pic cs:line-list1-4-end}{pic cs:line-list1-7-end}{hello}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now it looks like:
[image]

Comment: refer to this as well. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79787/70324