# Font encoding affects \box_wd:N calculation

Tags: fonts, boxes, expl3, dimensions

I have written a simple function to calculate the width of a line of text and display it using `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{domitian}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\let\oldstylenums\oldstyle
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l_my_otherbox
\dim_new:N \l_my_dim
\dim_new:N \l_my_htdim
\dim_new:N \l_my_dpdim
\NewDocumentCommand{\boxlen}{m}
{
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_my_otherbox {#1}
    \dim_set:Nn \l_my_dim  {\box_wd:N \l_my_otherbox}
    \dim_set:Nn \l_my_htdim  {\box_ht:N \l_my_otherbox}
    \dim_set:Nn \l_my_dpdim  {\box_dp:N \l_my_otherbox}
    \begin{tikzpicture}        
        \node[draw,text~width=9cm,align=left,fill=white,draw=black,inner~sep=0pt] (box) at (0,0)
        {#1};  
         \draw[line~width=2pt]~($(box.south~west)+(0,-.5cm)$)~--~+(9cm,0) node[below,pos=0.5] {9 cm};
         \draw[red,line~width=2pt]~let~\p1=(box.west),\p2=(box.base)~in~($(box.base)+(\x1-\x2,-\dim_use:N \l_my_dpdim)$)~--~+(\dim_use:N \l_my_dim,0) node[below,pos=0.5] 
         {\fp_eval:n {round(\dim_to_decimal_in_cm:n {\dim_use:N \l_my_dim},2)}cm};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
This part of the document uses the \verb+domitian+ font family:\par
\boxlen{Long word.}
\vskip 2ex
\boxlen{\textbf{Even longer} word.}
\vskip 2ex
\boxlen{\textbf{Emphasize a word} or do not emphasize a word.}
\vskip 2ex
\boxlen{Emphasize a word or do not emphasize a word.}

{  % use computer modern roman
\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont 
This part of the document uses the \verb+Computer Modern Roman+ font family:\par
\boxlen{Long word.}
\vskip 2ex
\boxlen{\textbf{Even longer} word.}
\vskip 2ex
\boxlen{\textbf{Emphasize a word} or do not emphasize a word.}
\vskip 2ex
\boxlen{Emphasize a word or do not emphasize a word.}
}
\end{document}
```

The function works fine when I use Computer Modern Roman (by the way it is really difficult to get the codes for the `\fontfamily` command). But if I use `domitian`, as the sentence gets longer the width calculated by `\box_wd` seems to be smaller than the actual length of the text.
[image]

It seems that `\box_wd` is written for specific font families so I wonder if there is a way to calculate an adjustment for non-standard font families.

Comment: you typeset the text in a specific font, and then box_wd (`\wd`) is the size of the text in that font. the box commands themselves do not select any font.

Comment: `\dim_set_eq:NN` is wrong and errors.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the problem is that tikz for some unknown reason changes \spaceskip and \xspaceskip in a node. With the option `text badly ragged` one gets the expected result https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132748/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes i was just posting a spaceskip answer:-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer perhaps you can point out some of the errors, thanks.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes it is as simple as putting the `text badly ragged` option

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the reason would be following plain tex: `\def\raggedright{\rightskip\z@ plus2em \spaceskip.3333em \xspaceskip.5em\relax}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify to

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{domitian}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\let\oldstylenums\oldstyle
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l_my_otherbox
\dim_new:N \l_my_dim
\dim_new:N \l_my_htdim
\dim_new:N \l_my_dpdim
\NewDocumentCommand{\boxlen}{m}
{
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_my_otherbox {#1}
    \dim_set_eq:NN \l_my_dim  {\box_wd:N \l_my_otherbox}
    \dim_set_eq:NN \l_my_htdim  {\box_ht:N \l_my_otherbox}
    \dim_set_eq:NN \l_my_dpdim  {\box_dp:N \l_my_otherbox}
    \begin{tikzpicture}        
        \node[draw,text~width=9cm,align=left,fill=white,draw=black,inner~sep=0pt] (box) at (0,0)
        {#1};  
        \node[draw,green,text~width=9cm,align=left,fill=white,draw=black,inner~sep=0pt] (boxx) at (0,.5)
        {\box_use:N\l_my_otherbox};  
         \draw[line~width=2pt]~($(box.south~west)+(0,-.5cm)$)~--~+(9cm,0) node[below,pos=0.5] {9 cm};
         \draw[red,line~width=2pt]~let~\p1=(box.west),\p2=(box.base)~in~($(box.base)+(\x1-\x2,-\dim_use:N \l_my_dpdim)$)~--~+(\dim_use:N \l_my_dim,0) node[below,pos=0.5] 
         {\fp_eval:n {round(\dim_to_decimal_in_cm:n {\dim_use:N \l_my_dim},2)}cm};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\showoutput
\begin{document}

\boxlen{\textbf{Emphasize a word} or do not emphasize a word.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

where you can see the red line is showing the width of the green original box.

In the black text you are re-setting the text in a 9cm minipage, raggedright, which adjusts `\spaceskip` so the inter-word space is different

```
................\glue(\spaceskip) 3.33298
................\T1/Domitian-TLF/bold/n/10 a
................\glue(\spaceskip) 3.33298
```

as opposed to

```
.................\glue 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.833
.................\T1/Domitian-TLF/bold/n/10 a
.................\glue 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.833
```

---

The problem here is that by default tikz is using the plain tex definition of `\raggedright` which is

```
\def\raggedright{\rightskip\z@ plus2em \spaceskip.3333em \xspaceskip.5em\relax}
```

so here the inter word space is unconditionally set to 1/3 em ignoring the (in this case tighter) space set by the font metrics.

If you use the `text badly ragged` option you use the standard latex definition which does not set spaceskip at all.

An alternative would be a version of the plain definition updated to use the `\fontdimen` parameters from the current font rather than assuming .3333em as a target width for a space.

The plain tex `\raggedright` version gets closer if it is changed to force the font-specified width rather than 1/3 em

[image]

If you add, after loading tikz

```
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{text ragged}[]%
{\def\tikz@text@action{\pgfutil@raggedright\rightskip0pt plus2em \spaceskip\fontdimen2\font \xspaceskip\fontdimen7\font}}%
\makeatother
```

but even then as this version of ragged right forces inter-word space to be even, you do not get a different space in the bold section as you would normally.

Depending on the real use case it may be better to not use a fixed with node and simply use a natural width node (which is an mbox) or as I do in the green text, re-use the box rather than re-setting the text with different settings.

Comment: is the solution to put the `text badly ragged` option in `\node`? (apologies but I cannot link your user id)

Comment: @TedBlack you can't link to me as comments under an answer automatically go to the poster, yes that or put in a bug report to tikz to fix the ragged right code

Comment: Thanks for your help, your answer has improved my understanding.

Comment: @TedBlack I added a final possible tikz update

Comment: Why is `\dim_set_eq:NN` rather than `\dim_set_eq:Nn` used here?

Comment: @cfr because it's wrong but I copied from the question without  looking too hard at the code

Comment: @cfr why is it wrong, the code works

Comment: `N` means single unbraced token, `n` means braced group. Depending on what the code actually does, if you use the wrong form it sometimes accidentally works unless you turn  on debug mode which does slower checks. @TedBlack

Comment: OK I will correct it, don’t want it to break in the future